# jquery, replace input with select for example time picker like in google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to reproduce following effect.
I have two input elements on form: 
class=time and id=timefrom
class=time and id=timeto

i want to hide/remove this elements create select element with hours and minutes  example
00:00
00:30
01:00
01:30
02:00
...

Second element should be dynamic
for example selecting in first element 01:00 should cause
change values in second element for example
01:30 (30 min)
02:00 (1h)
02:30 (1h 30 min)
i didn't find any plugin for this im trying reproduce 
this effect but with no luck :(
help

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like this timepicker better.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/